# If the Wish spell duplicates an Abjuration spell, does it charge the Arcane Ward?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

Inspired by the title of [this other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144884/38834)...

An [Abjuration Wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#SchoolofAbjuration) gains the following feature:

> **Arcane Ward**
>   Starting at 2nd level, you can weave magic around yourself for protection. When you **cast an abjuration spell** of 1st level or higher, you can simultaneously use a strand of the spell's magic to create a magical ward on yourself that lasts until you finish a long rest...
>   While the ward has 0 hit points, it can't absorb damage, but its magic remains. Whenever you **cast an abjuration spell of 1st level or higher**, the ward regains a number of hit points equal to twice the level of the spell.

The *[wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)* spell is classified as Conjuration. But it can duplicate any other spell.

If the spell being duplicated is Abjuration, can it start and/or charge up the Arcane Ward? Or it is still considered Conjuration?